# CloudKit/Firebase: is it possible to send not only push when a record changes but also mail?

Tags: ios, firebase, cloudkit

In my app I do need synchronization/communication between devices, therefore I need a serverside database. Whenever some special record changes, I need to send a push notification and/or an email.

It's an iOS-only app, so Cloudkit would be fine, but I don't think that it's possible to send an e-mail. Same fore Firebase. Am I overlooking something or are there very similar alternatives which are capable of both, sending push and mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since March 2017 there's an [integration between Google Cloud Functions and Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). This allows you to run JavaScript code on Google's servers in response to events that happen in Firebase. A node being written to the database is one such event, but there are many more [use-cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases).

Your use-case seems closest to [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation), which sends a welcome email when a user subscribes to some fictional newsletter.